# Assign value to objects made using Interface?

Tags: angular, typescript

It's been hours since I am trying to figure out solution to create objects. can't find anything online. I am not able to access user1 outside of the constructor. Please help.

```
        import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-first-folder',
      templateUrl: './first-folder.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./first-folder.component.css']
    })
    export class FirstFolderComponent implements OnInit {

      nameVar:string;
      passwordVar:string;
      @Input() test:string;



      constructor() {
        interface UserInface{
          name:string,
          password:string
        };
        var user1: UserInface;
       }


      ngOnInit() {

      }
      //function for button click
      submitBtn(){ 
          **//I am getting error here because i am trying to assign values to object.**
**//error "Property 'user1' does not exist on type "**
          this.user1.name = this.nameVar;
          this.user1.password = this.passwordVar


      }
    }
```

Comment: What is `this` in the submitBtn? Is it instance of `FirstFolderComponent` class?

Comment: you have defined user1 in constructor scope, thats why you can not access its value outside of scope. define user1 as a property in above constructor. so that, you can access value anywhere

Comment: An interface is just a contract you agree about the types of your variables. It doesn’t exist in the JavaScript generated. Define your interface / model outside your component class. You can define class constructors that use the interface (to enforce types in typescript) to do something similar to what you’re attempting.

Comment: Why do you want to use an interface instead of a class? If you want to create new objects anyway I would tend to use a class `User`. If you need a new user object/instance just create it with `this.user = new User();` the user class can serve as kind of interface too. You can still use the object literal to create a new user object if you want: `this.user = {name : 'thename', password: 'thepw'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Make your `interface` outside the class and `export` it and then use it inside the `class`. See below, I have made the `interface` outside the class and exported it.

[**Stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqbplt)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-folder',
  templateUrl: './first-folder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first-folder.component.css']
})

export class FirstFolderComponent implements OnInit {    
  nameVar:string;
  passwordVar:string;
  @Input() test:string;
  user1: UserInface;


   constructor() {
     this.user1 = {name: '', password: ''}; // You can remove this line if you don't want 
   }

   ngOnInit() {}

   submitBtn(){ 
     this.user1 = {name: 'Surjeet', password: 'Singh'};
    }
}

// paste this code at the end of the component
   export interface UserInface{
     name:string,
     password:string
   };
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you solution does not work?

You defined `var user1` in constructor and it is local variable for the constructor. You nave to create `user1` as class member (class property). So you have to use it as `this.user1` in constructor if you want it to be available in other methods of the class.

You need the following code:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

    interface UserInface{
      name:string,
      password:string
    };

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-first-folder',
      templateUrl: './first-folder.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./first-folder.component.css']
    })
    export class FirstFolderComponent implements OnInit {
      user1: UserInface = {};
      nameVar:string;
      passwordVar:string;
      @Input() test:string;

      //function for button click
      submitBtn(){ 
          this.user1.name = this.nameVar;
          this.user1.password = this.passwordVar
      }
    }
```

Note, that assign empty object at the init of the user1. You also can do this in constructor like:

```
constructor() {
  this.user1 = {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

 export interface UserInface{
      name:string,
      password:string
 };

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-folder',
  templateUrl: './first-folder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first-folder.component.css']
})
export class FirstFolderComponent implements OnInit {

  nameVar:string;
  passwordVar:string;
  user1: UserInface;
  @Input() test:string;

  constructor() {
  }


  ngOnInit() {

  }
  //function for button click
  submitBtn(){ 
      **//I am getting error here because i am trying to assign values to object.**
       **//error "Property 'user1' does not exist on type "**
      this.user1.name = this.nameVar;
      this.user1.password = this.passwordVar
```

Comment: `user1` is undefined. Can you fix this please? If you try to assign any property of undefined type you get error.